# Clojure: Timbre and clojure.test namespaces

Tags: clojure, namespaces, timbre

Trying to get [Timbre](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre) to load in my test project along with [clojure.test](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html). My first attempt is

```
(ns foo.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [foo.core :refer :all]))
```

which compiles until I follow the next step in the Timbre documentation, adding

```
(timbre/refer-timbre) ; Provides useful Timbre aliases in this ns
```

I now get the following compile error

```
IllegalStateException report already refers to #'clojure.test/report in namespace foo.core-test
clojure.lang.Namespace.warnOrFailOnReplace (Namespace.java:88)
```

ok, groovy, I'll try

```
(ns foo.core-test ; ------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-----
  (:require [clojure.test :exclude [report]]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [foo.core :refer :all]))
```

mmmm, nope. I notice that clojure has a `report`, too. How about

```
(ns foo.core-test
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [report])
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [foo.core :refer :all]))
```

mmmmm, nope.

I hacked around for a while till I got tired of combinatorial trial-and-error. I haven't found a way to make them coexist. Any clues, please & thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `report` in `clojure.core`. In your second `ns` form you seem to be missing `:refer :all` for `clojure.test`. Try the following form:

```
(ns foo.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all :exclude [report]]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [foo.core :refer :all]))
```

Comment: That definitely did not work :(  one of the many permutations I tried.

Comment: **EDIT**: restarting nrepl made this solution work. Some bogusly saved state in the nrepl fooled me by keeping the error state bogusly alive.